# Serializing threads across segue to tableView

Tags: iphone, multithreading, ipad, ios5, segue

I have a tableviewcontroller whose tableviewcells segue directly to another tableviewcontroller. The segue was created from the tableViewCell prototype to the "child" tableview in the storyboard. I am using prepareForSegue in the parent tableview as below. When threaded as below, the code that gets put "back" in the main thread (because it is UI-related) gets executed *after* the new child tableview's methods are executed (e.g. cellForRowAtIndexPath, numberOfRowsInSection, viewDidLoad). The result is the child tableView did not get built (e.g. numberRows=0).

I "fixed" this by executing a taleView reloadData inside the new view's setters (setPhotoList, setPhotoListTitle). Is there a better way to instead synchronize/serialize the main thread across a segue? My fix seems a bit inefficient because the child tableview gets drawn but must then be reloaded once or even twice if both setters (in this case) do a reload. Thanks.

```
- (void)prepareForSegue:(UIStoryboardSegue *)segue sender:(id)sender
{

UITableViewCell *cell = sender;
UIActivityIndicatorView *spinner = [[UIActivityIndicatorView alloc] initWithActivityIndicatorStyle: UIActivityIndicatorViewStyleWhiteLarge];

dispatch_queue_t downloadQueue = dispatch_queue_create("flickr downloader", NULL);
dispatch_async(downloadQueue, ^{

    NSIndexPath *indexPath = [self.tableView indexPathForCell:sender];        
    NSDictionary *place = [self.places objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
    NSArray *photosHere = [FlickrFetcher photosInPlace:place maxResults:MAX_NUM_PHOTOS];
    NSString *placeAll = [place objectForKey:FLICKR_PLACE_NAME];
    NSArray *placeComponents = [placeAll componentsSeparatedByString:@","];

    dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{

        if ([segue.identifier isEqualToString:@"Show Photos At Place"]) {
            [segue.destinationViewController setPhotoList:photosHere];
            [segue.destinationViewController setPhotoListTitle:[placeComponents objectAtIndex:0]];
        }         

    });
});
dispatch_release(downloadQueue);
```

}

Answer (score 0):

How about...

1. in child view controller's setters, set a flag. It indicates whether the child view controller should reload data or not.
2. in child view controller's `viewWillAppear` or `viewDidAppear`, reload data using `downloadQueue`, depending on the flag.

Comment: t_motooka... regarding your suggestions:

Comment: t_motooka... thanks, I think your suggestions here eliminates the double reloadData I created by doing this in the setters. But not sure this is what I am looking for, as I want to block the initial view loading until prepareForSegue completes.